# Storyboard compilation in resource bundles

Tags: ios, xcode

I have several watchOS targets which use the same resources, so to try and organise these as best I can, I have a resource bundle target which is built with each app. I then run a script to copy all the resources from the build bundle into the app target being built.

In Xcode 8.1, my watchOS apps crashed at launch:

> There doesn't seem to be a valid compiled storyboard at path '/.../App.app/MyStoryboard.storyboardc''

As a last resort I removed my Storyboard from the bundle and directly added it to each individual target. This solves my problem, the compilation appears to work. Is there something in particular about resource bundles in Xcode that prevents Storyboards from being compiled?

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to resolve by copying resources using script in the build phases?

Comment: @bensarz Well the purpose of the bundle is to gather all the resources, the script gets the assets and copies them into whatever app is being built. The bundle is a bit of a safety net.

Comment: Which version of iOS are you targeting? Are you using Swift or ObjC?

Comment: @bensarz I'm targeting iOS 9.3+, and using Objective-C.

Comment: I haven't used ObjC in a little while but using a dynamic framework instead of a Resource Bundle may very well lead you down a simpler road.  Dynamic frameworks fully support storyboards, asset catalogs, and their much easier to maintain. Not only that but they are now independently testable. Just a suggestion but I think it's something you should consider strongly.